# rename command not found when running Ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my VirtualBox on my Windows 10 PC.
One of the tasks I wanted to do, was rename a bunch of files with the .txt extension to a .html extension. After searching online, I found that using the rename command would work.

But when attempting to run rename, I get the following error:

> Command 'rename' not found. Did you mean:
>
> Command 'hrename' from deb hsfutils (3.2.6-14)
>
> Try: sudo apt install < deb name>

Upon trying

> sudo apt install rename

I get the following error:

> Unable to locate package rename

I also tried

> sudo apt update

But it did not work.

Could someone tell me what to do?

Comment: You'll want to use the `mv` command.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming? Write a complaint to Canonical that they did not copy the commands from windows. See https://ftp.kh.edu.tw/Linux/Redhat/en_6.2/doc/gsg/ch-doslinux.htm

Comment: The reason I haven't used the `mv` command is because I want to apply these changes to all files in the directory at once using a single command. There are additional regex operation I would like to perform, but this is a start. From what I've read, using the `mv` command to rename multiple files at once is not recommended, and one should use rename instead.

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and paste the following command

```
sudo apt-get install rename
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.

E: Unable to locate package rename

I ended up just downloaded the .deb file.

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/rename_1.30-1_all.deb.html

Make sure you have perl installed.
sudo apt install perl-base --upgrade

Just for the record, rename on Linux is NOT the same as rename on windows.  Rename is a powerful tool for doing batch file renames with complex patterns in one line that would otherwise take multiple lines with bash, find, mv, and other commands.